# Passing jquery string into cakephp controller

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cakephp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Passing jquery variable with json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12055417/passing-jquery-variable-with-json)

I am trying to pass a jquery variable from a view to my controller using this code

```
var str = 'Some data i need';


    $.post('Configs/', {data : str});
```

and then I am retrieving it in my controller with this code.

```
if($this->request->is('post'))
    {
       $value = $_POST['data'];

       if($value == null)
       {
           $this->Session->setFlash('null');
       }
       else
       {
        foreach($value as $v)
        {
            $this->Session->setFlash($v);       
        }
       }
    }
```

I can retrieve the array but when I try to iterate through $value all it prints out is the word 'Array'.

thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Instead of `$_POST['data']` use $this->request->params. This might help you to achieve the same.

Comment: No this just returns blank I just want to get the values from the string so i can write it to a text file but its after becoming a nightmare.

Comment: You need to log what you're submitting to know where the error is - i.e. `debug($_POST['data']); die;`

Answer (score 0):

Pass data as json string and in your controller convert this string into php array using `json_decode()`

Comment: Ye I have tried that but i keep getting the error:

json_decode() expects string to be passed in but is getting an array?